# I need to remove ghost inherited permission from a folder on Windows server

Tags: windows, permissions

I have a folder something like this E:\Folder1\Folder2
Folder2 shows that there is a permission of AD object which no longer exists (which is true). When I try to remove that permision - it is not possible as it is inherited from upper folder. Closer examination of ACLs of Folder2 shows that the inheritance is from taken from E: The problem is that E: and Folder1 does not have anything like that listed so I cannot remove it :/

I have tryed to disable inheritance, copy ACLs, remove all records, enable inheritance and boom the ghost persmision is back... I can probably try this on E: level, but it is on server with extremly complicated access rights and this would be a online suicide :)

Thank you for tips how to remove that ghost

Comment: You may try to move Folder2 elsewhere and then back. Same for Folder1.